# while running the update query in foxpro getting this error

Tags: foxpro

**while runing the following code for update :**

```php
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection");

$conn->Open('Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;
Data Source="C:\Users\TEMP.HIDEAZSERVER\Desktop\databaseetc\testdata";');

$query = "UPDATE sitedetl set NAME = \"AA\", CUST_CODE = \"Updated value\" "; 

$conn->Execute($query);

$query = "SELECT * FROM sitedetl WHERE UNIQUEID = '00000000190'";

$rs = $conn->Execute($query) or die("Error in query: $query. " . $conn->ErrorMsg());

while (!$rs->EOF) {

    echo " Got NAME: " . $rs->Fields("NAME") . " :: CUST_CODE: " . $rs->Fields
    ("CUST_CODE");

     $rs->MoveNext();
}
```

select query is running but update query is not running....

**I am getting this error while update query execute:**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '
Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro
Description: File 'ws_ri.prg' does not exist.' in D:\xampp\htdocs\websims\test_config.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\websims\test_config.php(7): com->Execute('UPDATE sitedetl...')
#1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\websims\test_config.php on line 7
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the 'ws_ri.prg' message is, but on the update statement, try using a single quote around name = 'AA', cust_code = 'Updated value'. VFP probably doesn't like double quotes inside of double quotes.

Comment: Could it be something that the DBC is calling to enforce referential integrity?

Comment: @Jerry: FoxPro is fine with double quotes, single quotes, or even square brackets.  (It's an odd, odd language.)

Comment: @Jerry, the outer double quotes are in PHP - the string that VFP sees would just have the inner sets, which is fine.  You'd get into trouble writing "blah = "blah"" in VFP, though - you'd have to use either single quotes or square braces on the outside.

Comment: @DougM This ability to use three separate things as string delimiters comes in sort of handy though!

Answer (score 3):

The FoxPro DBC has been configured so that the *sitedetl* table has a relational integrity trigger added on UPDATE, in this case "ws_ri.prg"

Likely whichever program originally created the database contained a definition for `ws_ri`, and since you aren't going through said executable you're being left with an error.  (This is why proper separation of concerns is a good idea, kids!)

To side-step the problem, you should be able to simply add a ws_ri.prg file to C:\Users\TEMP.HIDEAZSERVER\Desktop\databaseetc\testdata.

You may also want to try connecting to the DBC itself, rather than the folder.